# refresh page automatically, data is not updating

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, page-refresh

Hi guys so i am using javascript to update the page automatically every 5 seconds... But i have noticed the refresh is working but it is not updating my server side data... So the data grid should be updating and it is not... But if i press f5 then the data updates... here is my javascript in the markup.

```
<script>
    //refresh the page (without losing state)
    window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()', 5000); 
</script>
```

(In the head)

```
page load 

has all my data i need... 

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                if (DDLProduct.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    BindDropDownList();
                }

                BizManager mgr = new BizManager();
                mgr.CalcShiftPeriod();

                //stores the bizmanager shiftstart to a backing field
                _shiftStart = mgr.Shiftstart; 
                _shiftEnd = mgr.Shiftend;

#if DEBUG
                //tests these values if program is in debug version.
                _shiftStart = new DateTime(2013, 08, 27, 6, 00, 00); 

                //dismisses if in release version
                _shiftEnd = new DateTime(2013, 08, 27, 13, 59, 59); 
#endif
                //passing in the params to the refreshdata method.
                RefreshData(Product,  _shiftStart, _shiftEnd);
            }
        }
```

So in essence the page is refreshing but the data is not unless i do a f5 refresh.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Page_load gets executed when the page is refreshed?

Comment: how are you updating the display when the data is refreshed

Comment: Stored proc is what i am using

Answer (score 5):

You are not actually refreshin the page, but submitting the form, hence creating a postback. In your Page_Load, you don't refresh the data if it's postback.

Try changing the javascript to:

```
<script>
   window.setTimeout(function() {
         location.reload();
   }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: No this does not work, after 5 seconds i get a popup saying - to display the webpage again, the web browser needs to resend the information youve previously submitted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are Reloading your page in every 5 sec

answer by **Esko** will work for you but

You can also refresh through use of `Meta Refresh` like this

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
</head>
```

I  suggest you to do that like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>      
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- your GridView in UpdatePanel -->
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
```

Backend Code:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code to refresh after some interval
}
```

Comment: This loses my dropdown selection and resets back to the default page load.

Comment: that's why i already mention why you are reloading you can put your page content in an update panel and make a function to fetch data from database and call that through JavaScript timer

Comment: ok sorry for the newb question, but how do i achieve this, im new to c# and asp.net :)

Comment: I am using a ddl to update my gridview on selection so does the ddl need to be in an timer control too

Comment: Ok thanks for that, newbie question again, i have a gridview called gridview1, what goes in the contenttemplate, and also what goes into the timer1_tick method? and does this go in the page load?

Comment: in timer1_tick method you need to put your code for refreshing/Populating data and put your grid in ContentTemplate

Comment: <ContentTemplate> Gridview1 <ContentTemplate> and place what in the timer tick?

Comment: in imer tick put your code by winch you are trying to refresh data

Comment: I dont know what to put to refresh every 5 seconds :/

Comment: brother i have already mentions all thing that you need to do please go through my answer Interval="2000" means 2 sec